# Is there a way to allow ISJSON() to be less strict

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, json

I am trying to validate if some text, which is json, before processing it further.

I am using the `ISJSON` function in SQL Server 2016.

I have a problem that some of my json is slightly malformed; it contains unescaped newline char, quotes and tabs. (I may also get some trailing commas as well, but these are less of a concern).

Json libraries in languages like C# are more forgiving and just transform/ignore these small errors.

**Is there a way to allow ISJSON() to be less strict and accept unescaped newline, quote and tab chars?**

Or

**Is there a way in SQL to check if some text is valid json; which is forgiving of unescaped newline, quotes and tab chars?**

**Examples**:

`'[{"key1": "Some value",}]'    -- Trailing comma`

`'[{"key1": "Some \value"}]'    -- Unescaped backslash`

`'[{"key1": "Some   value"}]'   -- Unescaped tab`

`'[{"key1": "Some 
value"}]'                       -- Unescaped new line`

Comment: What you are describing is incoming data issue that you need to fix before validating. There are no knobs that you can turn on to make `isjson()` less strict.

Comment: @Kin I agree. However all of the C# libraries I have tried will just transform/ignore these small errors; which is desirable in 99% of all cases.  But in this case wont stop bad json getting trough to the DB and failing there. (This is an error we are having in production) Which I why I was looking to see if is a way to get `ISJSON()` to be more forgiving. ( I am also looking into finding a stricter parser upstream).  Also due to the data provenance requirements I can't use C# (etc.) to transform the data prior to it landing in the DB. Any other suggestions **gladly** accepted.